# Full outer join joining together every record multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query below:

```
select 

       cu.course_id      as 'bb_course_id',
       cu.user_id        as 'bb_user_id',
       cu.role           as 'bb_role',
       cu.available_ind  as 'bb_available_ind',
       CASE cu.row_status WHEN 0 THEN 'ENABLED' ELSE 'DISABLED' END AS 'bb_row_status',
       eff.course_id     as 'registrar_course_id',
       eff.user_id       as 'registrar_user_id',
       eff.role          as 'registrar_role',
       eff.available_ind as 'registrar_available_ind',
       CASE eff.row_status WHEN 'DISABLE' THEN 'DISABLED' END as 'registrar_row_status'

into enrollments_comparison_temp
from narrowed_users_enrollments cu 
full outer join enrollments_feed_file  eff on cu.course_id = eff.course_id
```

Quick background: I'm taking the data from a replicated table and selecting it into `narrowed_users_enrollments` based on some criteria. In a script I'm taking a text feed file, with enrollment data, and inserting it into `enrollments_feed_file`. The purpose is to compare the most recent enrollment data with enrollments already in the database.

However the issue is that joining these tables results in about 160,000 rows when I'm really only expecting about 22,000. The point of doing this comparison is so that I can look for nulled values on either side of the join. For example, if the table on the right contains a null, then disable the enrollment record. If the table on the left contains a null, then add this student's enrollment.

I know it's a little off because I'm not using PKs or FKs. This is what is selected into the table:

Here's a screenshot showing a select * from the enrollments table on the left and a feed file on the right.

http://i.imgur.com/0ZPZ9HS.png

Here's a screenshot showing the newly created table from the full outer join.

http://i.imgur.com/89ssAkS.png

As you can see even though there there's only one matching enrollment(the matching jmartinez12 columns), there's 4 extra rows created for the same record on the left for the enrollments on the right. What I'm trying to get is for it to be 5 rows, with the first being how it is in the screenshot(matching pre-existing enrollment and enrollment in the feed file), BUT, the next 4 rows with the `bb_*` columns should be NULL up to the `registrar_course_id`.

Am I overlooking something simple here? I've tried a select distinct and I've added a where clause specifying when the course_ids are equal however that ensures that I won't get null rows which I need. I have also joined the tables on the user_id however the results are still the same.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide some sample source data which  results in rows that are "not legit"

Comment: Okay I'll try a better example with a small sample.

Comment: And don't include data that mean nothing and exclude pertinent data.  select eff.course_id as 'registrar_course_id', eff.course_id as 'registrar_course_id'

Comment: Bout to edit my post with a more illustrated example.

Comment: Why would you expect the userID to match?  That is not a join condition.

Comment: You do realize that a join IS a match right? And a full outer join displays all rows even if there isn't a match? I CAN expect the USER ID to match in most cases.

Comment: -1  Clearly you don't realize what a join condition IS.  user_id is not a condition of the join so you CAN ExpECT nothing about user_id.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here between us. I'm not saying I'm joining on the user_id, I know what I'm joining on, but my question says that I've already tried different join conditions, one being the user_id, which, will match in some cases. When it doesn't, there would either be a null on the left or right table. Understand?

Comment: What I understand is if you are not joining on userID and userID is not in the where then you can have no expectations relative to userID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to also join on:

```
ON cu.course_id = eff.course_id AND cu.user_id = eff.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick suggestion is to add the `DISTNCT` clause. If the records you are setting are complete duplicates that may cut it down to what you are expecting.